# KerT and ImT linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove :

$\mathrm{Im}( T^2) = \mathrm{Im} (T) $ if and only if $\mathrm{Ker}(T) = \mathrm{Ker}(T^2)$

T:V->V

someone has an Idea?

thank you.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention the definition space has *finite* dimension, otherwise the claim is not true in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the [rank nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

This hint is what you should think of any time that you need to relate a kernel to an image or vice versa.

It also helps to keep in mind that in general, $\text{Im}(T^2) \subseteq \text{Im}(T)$ and $\ker(T^2) \supseteq \ker(T)$.